# Is ordering data a task that needs to be performed by the view or the controller?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I have data that needs to be displayed in a (html) table. I'm using Laravel in my application.
The data is coming from a database and I would like to display it ordered alphabetically. This (html) table will contain more than one column.

For example, if the data is: grape, apple, pear, peach, orange, strawberry, fig, raspberry, blueberry.

It can be sorted as:

apple
blueberry
fig
grape
orange
peach
pear
raspberry
strawberry

or

apple peach
blueberry pear
fig raspberry
grape strawberry
orange

and go on (increasing the number of columns).

Who is responsible for ordering the data? The controller when is sending data to the view or the view after receiving the data coming from the controller?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a problem that is more suited for [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You should order the data when queering the database in your controller.

Comment: @Jerodev when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 1):

I would sort on the database query since it will always be faster than letting an interpreted scripting language like PHP handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the ordering is made in the controller, using a [Eloquent model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent) or a [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset). The you pass the ordered collection to the view.